# How do add ucanaccess maven dependency in pom.xml

Tags: maven, dependencies, ucanaccess

I can't get the maven dependency for ucanaccess to work:
        
            net.ucanaccess
            ucanaccess
            2.X.X

It doesn't seem to be available?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that ucanaccess is not currently available from maven central (based on googling for it and finding [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/ucanaccess/discussion/general/thread/3ab11fb4/)).

I'd recommend downloading it from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ucanaccess/files/?source=navbar), extracting the jar, and installing the jar in your local repo using the instructions from the [maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#importing-jars):

```
mvn install:install-file
    -Dfile=<path-to-file>
    -DgroupId=<group-id>
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id>
    -Dversion=<version>
    -Dpackaging=<packaging>
    -DgeneratePom=true

Where: <path-to-file> the path to the file to load
       <group-id> the group that the file should be registered under
       <artifact-id> the artifact name for the file
       <version> the version of the file
       <packaging> the packaging of the file e.g. jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you look on http://mvnrepository.com/ to check whether your dependency is present or not ?

If not you should drop the jar in your classpath by yourself or create the appropriate directory in your local maven repository at %HOME%.m2\repository.